# PHP Parser Using simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

This is a beginners question (sorry for that); I am using simplexml_load_string() php function to parse an RSS feed, my code looks like this:

```
<?php

$url    = "http://www.zdnet.com/blog/rss.xml";
$xml    = file_get_contents($url);
$feed   = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($feed->channel as $channel) {
    echo "Link : " . $channel->link . "<P>";
    echo "Image URL : " . $channel->image->url . "<P>";
}

foreach($feed->channel->item as $item) {
    echo "<HR><P>";
    echo "Link : " . $item->link . "<P>";
    echo "Title : " . $item->title . "<P>";
    echo "Description : " . $item->description . "<P>";
    echo "Date : " . $item->pubDate . "<P>";
}

?>
```

Which is working fine but the XML file has some  tags that look like this:

```
<media:credit role="author">
<![CDATA[ James Kendrick ]]>
</media:credit>

<media:text type="html">
<![CDATA[
<figure class="alignRight"><a href="/i/story/70/00/034218/kindle-iphone-2.jpg" target="_blank">     
<img title="kindle-iphone-2" alt="kindle-iphone-2" src="http://cdn-static.zdnet.com/1.jpg"> 
height="237" width="200"></a><figcaption>(I
]]>

<![CDATA[
mage: James Kendrick/ ZDNet)</figcaption></figure> <p>Regular readers know I am a tablet guy
]]>
</media:text>
```

How can I parse these  tags?

Thanks

Comment: Usually you wont parse CDATA sections at all. Just handle the as plain text

Comment: You may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547992/xml-cdata-not-returning-properly-with-simplexml-load-string-nor-simplexmleleme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing that nodes with namespaces you could use `->children()` in that case:

```
$url = "http://www.zdnet.com/blog/rss.xml";
$feed = simplexml_load_file($url, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach($feed->channel->item as $item) {
    echo "<HR><P>";
    echo "Link : " . $item->link . "<P>";
    echo "Title : " . $item->title . "<P>";
    echo "Description : " . $item->description . "<P>";
    echo "Date : " . $item->pubDate . "<P>";

    $media = $item->children('media', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'); // medias
    // then just loop the children
    // foreach($media as $m) {}
    $s = $item->children('s', 'http://www.zdnet.com/search'); // ss
}
```