# How to parse soap xml response that have several namespaces defined. I need to parse the Articles array returned

Tags: php, xml, parsing, curl, soap

The soap xml reponse is as such:

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS1="urn:TPAPIPosIntfU-ITPAPIPOS">
          <NS1:GetArticlesInfoResponse xmlns:NS2="urn:TPAPIPosIntfU" xmlns:NS3="urn:TPAPIPosTypesU">
             <return xsi:type="NS2:TGetArticlesInfoResponse">
                <ReturnCode xsi:type="xsd:int">0</ReturnCode>
                <ReturnMessage xsi:type="xsd:string">ok</ReturnMessage>
                <Articles xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TArticleInfo[x]">...</Articles>
                <Extra xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TExtraInfo[0]"/>
             </return>
          </NS1:GetArticlesInfoResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And this is the Articles array that i need to parse:

```
<item xsi:type="NS3:TArticleInfo">
    <ArticleId xsi:type="xsd:long">5000001716</ArticleId>
    <ArticleName xsi:type="xsd:string">Coca Cola</ArticleName>
    <ArticleNumber xsi:type="xsd:int">1</ArticleNumber>
    <Available xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:long[3]">
        <item>5000000210</item>
        <item>5000000208</item>
        <item>5000000209</item>
    </Available>
    <DepartmentId xsi:type="xsd:long">5000000170</DepartmentId>
    <Prices xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TItemPrice[2]">
        <item xsi:type="NS3:TItemPrice">
        <ArticleId xsi:type="xsd:long">5000001716</ArticleId>
        <PriceId xsi:type="xsd:long">5000000206</PriceId>
        <Amount xsi:type="xsd:double">2</Amount>
        <Vat xsi:type="xsd:double">21</Vat>
        <Extra xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TExtraInfo[0]"/>
    </item>
    <item xsi:type="NS3:TItemPrice">
        <ArticleId xsi:type="xsd:long">5000001716</ArticleId>
        <PriceId xsi:type="xsd:long">5000000207</PriceId>
        <Amount xsi:type="xsd:double">1.7</Amount>
        <Vat xsi:type="xsd:double">12</Vat>
        <Extra xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TExtraInfo[0]"/>
    </item>
    </Prices>
    <FreeOption xsi:type="xsd:long">5000000145</FreeOption>
    <Options xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:long[1]">
        <item>5000000143</item>
    </Options>
    <IsMenu xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</IsMenu>
    <IsManualPrice xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</IsManualPrice>
    <IsActive xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</IsActive>
    <Promo xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</Promo>
    <HqId xsi:type="xsd:string">Coca Cola</HqId>
    <Extra xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TExtraInfo[5]">
        <item xsi:type="NS3:TExtraInfo">
            <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">daily_stock_active</Key>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</Value>
            <Extra xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TExtraInfo[0]"/>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="NS3:TExtraInfo">
            <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">daily_stock_qty</Key>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</Value>
            <Extra xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TExtraInfo[0]"/>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="NS3:TExtraInfo">
            <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">purchase_price</Key>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">0.0000</Value>
            <Extra xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TExtraInfo[0]"/>
            </item>
        <item xsi:type="NS3:TExtraInfo">
            <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">course_id</Key>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">5000001331</Value>
            <Extra xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TExtraInfo[0]"/>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="NS3:TExtraInfo">
            <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">info</Key>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
            <Extra xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TExtraInfo[0]"/>
        </item>
    </Extra>
</item>
Parameter   Type    Description
ArticleId   Long    Internal Id of this Article
ArticleName String  Name of this Article
ArticleNumber   Integer Number of this Article
Available   [Long]  List of Sales Area Id's where this Article is available
Prices  [ItemPrice] List of Prices for this Article
DepartmentId    Long    Id of the Department where this Article belongs to
FreeOption  Long    Free Option ID
Options [Long]  List of must-have options
IsMenu  Boolean Returns true if this Article is a menu
IsManualPrice   Boolean Returns true if this Article requires a manual price input when ordered
IsActive    Boolean Returns if true is this Article is active
Promo   Boolean Return true if this Article is a Cobmo/Promo article
HqId    String  HQ Id
Extra   [ExtraInfo] List of extra fields
List of available extra fields:

Key Description
course_id   Only return articles of a specific course
daily_stock_active  1/0 (if DailyStock=1 was specified in request’s Extra fields)
daily_stock_qty Daily stock quantity (if DailyStock=1 was specified in request’s Extra fields)
info    Article info (tab 9 of the article settings in back-office)
plu When PLU is not zero
purchase_price  Purchase price
ArticleShort
ArticleShort Object

<item xsi:type="NS3:TArticleShort">
    <ArticleId xsi:type="xsd:long">5000001716</ArticleId>
    <ArticleName xsi:type="xsd:string">Coca Cola</ArticleName>
    <ArticleNumber xsi:type="xsd:int">1</ArticleNumber>
    <SalesAreaId xsi:type="xsd:long">5000000210</SalesAreaId>
    <DepartmentId xsi:type="xsd:long">5000000170</DepartmentId>
    <HqId xsi:type="xsd:string">Coca Cola</HqId>
    <Extra xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS3:TExtraInfo[0]"/>
</item>
```

How can I parse this soap XML response in php curl to get the Articles array data? I have tried SimpleXMLElement but I am unable to parse this.

I have surfed a lot for answers but not able to get the correct parsing technique. Shall I use Xpaths if yes, then how to create an XPath to parse the articles array?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898660/cannot-parse-xml-using-simplexml-load-string/55898990#55898990 for a similar problem and how to approach it perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution using XPath and SimpleXML, which from the look of the XML doesn't involve namespaces for the XPath itself.  This loads the XML and then looks for an element called `<return>` with a direct descendant called `<Articles>`.  As `xpath()` returns a list of nodes, it then just picks the first one (using `[0]`) and iterates of the `<item>` elements enclosed and outputs the `<ArticleId>` elements value....

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$articles = $xml->xpath("//return/Articles");

foreach ( $articles[0]->item as $item )    {
    echo (string)$item->ArticleId.PHP_EOL;
}
```

With the test data this gives...

```
5000001716
5000001716
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Helped me understand the xpath.